# libgdx. How create destructible terrain?

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, terrain

I recently started working with libgdx and I have task create destructible terrain like worms game. I do not know where to start. Maybe need to use box2d engine or something else. 
Ps
when creating a map, I use tail map editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Terrain I think there is no out of the box solution, at least not wihtout box2d. But some years ago there was a project in the [libgdx-utils](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/net.dermetfan.gdx.physics.box2d.Breakable) package, which had breakable box2d objects.

I also just found another [blog post](http://www.quailshillstudio.com/en/blog/article/00001-destructible-terrain-libgdx-box2d-polygon-clipping-algorithm/) about, what you are lookign for, maybe it helps.